# Validate password and confirm password Ng2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Here are my codes:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="doRegister()">
            <div 
                class="form-group" 
                [ngClass]="{'has-danger': registerForm.controls.email.invalid 
                    && !registerForm.controls.email.pristine}">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input
                  formControlName="email"
                  name="email"
                  [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': registerForm.controls.email.invalid 
                    && !registerForm.controls.email.pristine}"
                  class="form-control"
                  type="email" />
            </div>
            <div 
                class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-danger': registerForm.controls.password.invalid 
                    && !registerForm.controls.password.pristine}">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input
                  class="form-control"
                  type="password"
                  formControlName="password"
                  name="password"
                  [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': registerForm.controls.password.invalid 
                    && !registerForm.controls.password.pristine}" >
            </div>
            <div 
                class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-danger': registerForm.controls.passwordConfirm.invalid}" >
                <label>Password Confirm</label>
                <input
                  [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': registerForm.controls.passwordConfirm.invalid}"
                  class="form-control"
                  type="password"
                  formControlName="passwordConfirm"
                  name="passwordConfirm" >
            </div>
            <button [disabled]="!registerForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
```

And the form init part:

```
this.registerForm = this.formbuilder.group({
        email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, validateEmail])],
        password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])],
        passwordConfirm: ['', ]
    })
```

Now I want to validate the password and passwordConfirm field but I don't know how, I tried to created a directive but I can't pass the formcontrol directly into it. Thank you.

Edit:

```
<div
                class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-danger': registerForm.controls.password.invalid
                    && !registerForm.controls.password.pristine}">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input
                  formControlName="password"
                  name="password"
                  class="form-control"
                  [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': registerForm.controls.password.invalid
                    && !registerForm.controls.password.pristine}"
                  type="password"
                  validateEqual="registerForm.controls.passwordConfirm"
                  reverse="true" >
            </div>
            <div
                class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-danger': registerForm.controls.passwordConfirm.invalid}" >
                <label>Password Confirm</label>
                <input
                  formControlName="passwordConfirm"
                  name="passwordConfirm"
                  [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': registerForm.controls.passwordConfirm.invalid}"
                  class="form-control"
                  type="password"
                  validateEqual="registerForm.controls.password" >
            </div>
```

It just simply doesn't work, no error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [password matching(password and conform password) validation using ionic2 and angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718191/password-matchingpassword-and-conform-password-validation-using-ionic2-and-ang)

Comment: It doesn't work thought

Comment: any error you are getting ?

Comment: I edited my post, can you take a look, @ranakrunal9? Thanks.

Comment: Someone please help me with this, I'm very new to Angular 2 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using `validateEqual` directive use below HTML :

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-danger': registerForm.controls.password.invalid && !registerForm.controls.password.pristine}">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input formControlName="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': registerForm.controls.password.invalid && !registerForm.controls.password.pristine}" validateEqual="passwordConfirm" reverse="true" >
</div>
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-danger': registerForm.controls.passwordConfirm.invalid}">
    <label>Password Confirm</label>
    <input formControlName="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': registerForm.controls.passwordConfirm.invalid}" class="form-control" type="password" validateEqual="password" >
</div>
```

Comment: Now I got 
`Unable to delete property 'validateEqual' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: It's very weird, I add it to the module file and still can't work, I tried 3 times...

Comment: @LeDinhNhatKhanh just an fyi, when using registerForm.controls.password.invalid it's safer to use registerForm.get('password).invalid as the former can create errors dureing transpiling. [https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts)